# Coloring a image partialy using javascript based on user selection

Tags: javascript, css

i have this "Time line", its horizontal it goes like this

00|01|02|03|etc up to 23

Every span that contains a number is 17 pixels, and the "|" line is 1 pixel, the whole image is 431x20 pixels.

I have 2  tags, the user is supposed to pick a "Start" time and a "End" time, i want to know how i can color the image partially using javascript, i am thinking i could put some CSS over it, such as  over the image, but i have no idea how to do this using javascript, any help would be greatly apriciated.

Comment: We need more details on your scenario. Is the timeline an image itself? What do you mean by partially coloring an image - overlaying it with a layer, switching backgrounds...?

Comment: What is your "image"? Is it Image element of HTML?

Comment: the timeline is a image, and it looks exactly like this:

00|01|02|03|etc up to 23

by coloring i mean partially covering the "from - to" part, as in, user selects "from 13" "to 16"

13-14-15-16 need to be colord

Comment: Oh, I see. What about overlaying it with semi-transparent PNG with different left offset? Why don't you rewrite your "timeline" into HTML table? Then you can change CSS background of table cell.

Comment: oh, thats a good idea! i will do that

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me as fairly simple to absolutely position a DIV on top of your image, with the same height, whatever color you choose, and some appropriate opacity, setting its left edge to (and this is a quick calculation and might be wrong) image.left + (18 * from), and its width to 18 * (to - from + 1) - 1.

But is there a great reason to make your timeline an image in the first place?  It sounds even better to me to have a collection of nodes that either have or don't have a "selected" class, each with a "00" - "23" text marker on them.  No images needed.